# Prefix best practice, should we use framework name or theme name?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Assuming there is the theme A built on top of the theme framework B, A has its post meta named like `a_{post_meta_created_by_a}`, it's ok.

But for post meta created by B, there are two choices:

1. Use B's name, naming its post meta as `b_{post_meta_created_by_b}`
2. Use A's name, so `a_{post_meta_created_by_b}`

Which is the best?